# MYSQL - constraint for variable used a primary key and a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-key

How do I display a variable which is bring used as a primary key and a foreign key at the same time?

Only using a primary key:

**Patient Table**

```
patientID (pk)
first_name
surname 
address 
blood_type 
email
```

I know how to show a primary key alone : CONSTRAINT PATIENT_pk primary key (patientID)

But now how do I do it when it's both?

**Medical_Rec**

```
staffID (pk/fk) 
patientID (pk/fk) 
prescID (pk/fk)
medID (pk/fk) 
condition
```

Comment: What do you mean by _display a variable_? Are you trying to query the data in your DB? Create some tables? Display table definitions?

Comment: I mean when you create the table and you have the CONSTRAINTS underneath where you put the variables and their types.. How do you now show that the variable is a primary and a foreign key?
eg. CONSTRAINT med_pk primary key and foreign key (staffID)?
I am not sure how to write the CONSTRAINT when it is being used for a primary key and a foreign key

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) will help.